# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Xcode Unity

Tags: swift, xcode, unity-game-engine

I did change library path search, delete derived data, and still have problem like this

[[image: Screenshot][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abkVA.png)

Comment: have you tried to clean the build?  Shift+CMD+K

Comment: Yes I did, i clean every build

Comment: Ok, the error message suggested to use -v. Did you do that?